# access declaration can only be applied to a base class member

Tags: c++, observer-pattern

i'm using the observer pattern. I've a class that implements the publisher class:

```
class foo : public Publisher<const RecoveryState &>,
       public Publisher<char &>,
```

therin in try to bind the attach function:

```
using Publisher<const RecoveryState &>::attach;
using Publisher<const char &>::attach;
```

the RecoveryState works, but at the char line the following error occurs:

> Error 5   error C3210: 'Publisher' : access declaration can
>   only be applied to a base class
>   member    c:\projekte\ps3controlmodule\tbfcontrol\tbfcmdhandler.h 363

Comment: Not the answer you are looking for, but prefer nested classes with delegation over multiple inheritance.  I think this way, the problem will not be present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a discrepancy "char&" vs. "const char&".

Answer (score 1):

'Publisher<const char &>' is not a base class - 'Publisher<char &>' is.